# How to recover an integer from an ActiveSupport::Duration object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, duration, activesupport

How can I recover the integer corresponding to an ActiveSupport::Duration object?

At the same time, is it possible to recover the type of time duration?

exemple:

```
foo = 2.day
bar = foo.duration_integer  # expected "2"
baz = foo.duration_type     # expected "day" or "days"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`parts`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb#L10) accessor like this. The first element is what you call the `duration_type` and the last one the integer value:

```
2.day.parts
=> [:days, 2]
```