# How can I know what ActiveSupport Duration was used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

Looking at "[How to recover an integer from an ActiveSupport::Duration object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647309)", I can see it should be possible, but for:

```
2.hours.parts
```

I get:

```
[[:seconds, 7200]]
```

How can this be done better so that I have:

```
[[:hours, 2]]
```

Comment: @mudasobwa getting error - `NameError: uninitialized constant Duration`

Answer (score 1):

That may not be possible.

If you look at implementation of [core-extensions in Active Support, time.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb), `parts` is set to `:seconds` for `Duration` instances constructed using `Numeric#hours` or `Numeric#minutes` or `Numeric#seconds`.

```
p 1.hour     # 3600 seconds
p 2.minutes  # 120 seconds
p 30.seconds # 30 seconds
```

Hence, you will always see something like below for all duration which are in hours, minutes or seconds, if you inspect the `Duration#parts` attribute

```
[[:seconds, 7200]]
```

Comment: I see. Maybe it's time to contribute a bit to Rails :)